# DCC Error : E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Result'

Tags: delphi, debugging, syntax-error

I was screwing around with debug setting on my compiler and now I am getting these errors that I can't seem to get rid of.

**[DCC Error] HASPCODE.PAS(223): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'Result'**

It didn't complain before, but now no matter what I said the debugging settings to it keeps raising the above error just for the HASPCODE.PAS file only.

For instance, Here is one of the functions where the error is raised.

```
function THasp.IsHasp:Boolean;
begin
  Result := fIsHasp; <<=======
end;
```

Comment: It would really help if we could see the code...

Comment: What is that HASPCODE.PAS ? Show us the code of it.

Comment: it is just a unit file with class and its procedures and functions.

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using?

Comment: As a complete aside, you should choose something that's not HASP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The implicit function Result variable is only available when the [extended syntax compiler](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Extended_syntax_%28Delphi%29) option is enabled.

> The Result variable. In the {$X+} mode, the predefined
>   variable Result can be used within a function body to hold
>   the function's return value.

Comment: David Heffernan, your answer is fantastic my friend. Long time no see :) Glad to see you again.